# Updating attributes through a different object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a ridiculously hard time trying to figure out how to do this. I have been at it literally all day.

I have an Account class and a Transaction class.
Accounts are created with a balance and I want the Transaction amount, depending on its type, to either add or subtract from the balance.

I want to be able to update the Account balance every time a transaction is created. This is for a personal finance application. As of now when I create a new transaction, nothing happens to the account balance.

#### accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end

  def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
  end

  def edit
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save
        format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'Account was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @account, status: :created, location: @account }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
        format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'Account was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /accounts/1
  # DELETE /accounts/1.json
  def destroy
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  @account.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to accounts_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
  end

  def update_balance
  @a = Account.find(params[:id])
  @a.transactions.each do |t| 
    @update_balance = t.t_type + @a.balance
    @a.update_attributes(:balance => @update_balance)
  end
  end
end
```

#### transactions_controller.rb

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
    @transaction = @account.transactions.create(params[:transaction])
    redirect_to account_path(@account)
  end
end
```

#### transaction.rb

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  attr_accessible :amount, :category, :t_type
end
```

#### account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :balance, :name
  has_many :transactions
end
```

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong or can point me in the direction of a good thorough explanation, that would be great. I am so lost at this point.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific describing your problem.

Comment: edited for clarity. hopefully that's better.

Comment: Please include the relevant code here instead of linking to an external site. If the external site changes or goes away, this question then loses context and becomes useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :balance, :name
  has_many :transactions

  def update_with_transaction(transaction)
    return unless self.transactions.include? transaction
    if transaction.t_type.eql? SOME_TYPE
      self.balance += transaction.ammount
    else 
      self.balance -= transaction.ammount
    end
    save
  end
end

class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
    @transaction = account.transactions.create(params[:transaction])
    account.update_with_transaction(@transaction)
    redirect_to account_path(account)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I really appreciate it. I obviously am still new to RoR so I'm still working on grasping what needs to go where.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t update because you haven’t told it to. Create an [`after_create` callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) to do so:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  after_create :update_account_balance

  private

  def update_account_balance
    account.balance += amount
    account.save
  end
end
```

Adjust as needed. Note that this won’t handle updates to a transaction’s amount, which is left as an exercise for the reader.